# Java Regex for pattern with two substrings not containing a particular substring in between

Tags: java, regex

Lets say I have the following string : `Stackoverflow is here to help you`.

My regex should be such that `is` and `here` should not contain a `not` in between. Other substrings can be present. And `not` can be present anywhere else in the string.

Eg:

`Stackoverflow is not here to help you` - should not match

`Stackoverflow is here to help you` - should match

`Stackoverflow is always here to help you` - should match

`Stackoverflow is not always here to help you` - should not match

Comment: Sounds like you just want to check if there's `not` between `is` and `here`. In that case you can simply look for a substring that matches `is\\s+not\\s+here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex would work:

```
^.* is((?!not).)* here .*$
```

Here is an example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LcsX6R/3)

> ^: asserts position at start of a line
>
> .*
>   matches any character
>
> " is": matches the signal word "is" (with blanks to match only "is")
>
> ((?!not).)*: matches all words which are not "not"
>
> " here ": matches the signal word "here" (with blanks to match only "here")
>
> .*
>   matches any character
>
> $ asserts position at the end of a line

**UPDATE**

```
^.* is((?! not )( .*))* here .*$
```

With that regex you can specify that the regx will work on only "is" and "here".

> ( .*): blank for a new word

Updated example: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LcsX6R/4)

Comment: Worked. Thanks. It would be great if the regex could be explained. I tried similar regex and messed up the negative lookahead part. Will be useful for me and others who are new to regex.

Comment: This does not work if a word containing "not" is between is and here.
And "is" or "here" can be part of words as well (like analys*is*)

Comment: Updated my answer and the example with surrounding blanks at the words here and is. Thanks @DavidAmar

Comment: @DavidAmar The first unedited version solved my actual usecase. I actually needed substrings and not actual words. Thanks anyway.

Comment: your updated version doesn't work if "here" ends the sentence
. And it will match also **it is sometimes (and sometimes not) here to help**

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`\bis\b(\W+\b(?!not\b)\w+\b)*?\W+\bhere\b`

Explanations:

1. `\bis\b`: match word *is*, and not a part of a word that would contain *is*
2. `(\W+\b(?!not\b)\w+\b)*?`: match the inner group any number of times in a lazy approach (faster for very long sentences)
3. ```\W+\b(?!not\b)\w+\b``: inner group matches non-word chars, then a word start: it cannot be "*not[end of word]*" and reads the whole word
4. `\W+\bhere\b`: match non-word chars, then the word *here* (and not something that would start with *here*)

```
Stackoverflow is not here to help you does not match.
Stackoverflow is here to help you matches: at index 14 [is here]
Stackoverflow is always here to help you matches: at index 14 [is always here]
Stackoverflow is not always here to help you does not match.
Stackoverflow is notoriously here to help you matches: at index 14 [is notoriously here]
Analysis completed here does not match.
Analysis is completed here matches: at index 9 [is completed here]
Analysis is completed there does not match.
Analysis ist completed there does not match.
ishere does not match.
```